# Integrate awk one-liner into awk script?

Tags: linux, awk

If I have this one-liner

```
$ echo 0123456789ab | awk '{gsub(/..\B/,"&:")}1'
01:23:45:67:89:ab
```

which I would like to use in an awk script, and therefore tries

```
cat $hosts | awk '{
    print "host "$5" {"
    print "  option host-name \""$5"\";"
    print "  hardware ethernet "$3";"
    x = {gsub(/..\B/,"&:")}1
    print "  fixed-address "print x";"
    print "}"
    print ""
}' > /etc/dhcp/reservations.conf
```

but it fails with

```
awk: cmd. line:5:     x = {gsub(/..\B/,"&:")}1
awk: cmd. line:5:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:6:     print "  fixed-address "print x";"
awk: cmd. line:6:                             ^ syntax error
```

**Question**

Does anyone know how to integrate such one-liners into an awk script?

Comment: What is your input file?

Comment: You should remove the `{` around the `gsub` command as this is not a one-liner anymore (and maybe remove the `1` entirely)

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting, you need NOT to use `cat` with `awk`, `awk` could read files by itself too.

Comment: Show us the input file you are working with? What is the value that you want to `gsub()` on? What is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save `{` in to a variable since it denotes some action. Moreover in case you save output of `sub` or `gsub` it always gives you the count of substitutes it made to line/variable. so better try to change that code line to following.

Change your 2 lines:

```
x = {gsub(/..\B/,"&:")}1
print "  fixed-address "print x";"
```

To:

```
new_line=$0
gsub(/..\B/,"&:",new_line)
print "  fixed-address "new_line";"
```

By doing above your actual line's value will NEVER change and you could use it doing other stuff later point of time in your code too. I haven't tested above since samples were not given but it should work.